# AngularJS page hopping around with semanticUI Tabs

Tags: angularjs, semantic-ui

I have built an app that utilizes semantic UI tabs and ui-router. Every time I switch tabs, the page 'snaps' to the div where the tabs are being held, instead of maintaining its position. I do not have any idea where to even begin looking.

*Note* I faced another similar issue earlier on in the build, where [angularUI grid was causing the page to hop around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41551963/angular-ui-grid-snapping-when-clinking-a-row) and snap to the view. For the sake of trying to fix the current issue, I have commented out any angularUI grid line that could have caused the issue, leading me to believe it has something to do with semantic.

Has anyone faced an issue like this? Where do I even begin troubleshooting?

*please note, I am scrolling back up in the gif, then clicking a tab, where it snaps back down
[image]

Comment: Checkout the `autoscroll` [directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#autoscroll) in Angular UI Router. I'm pretty sure that is what is causing it...

Comment: I tried to set autoscroll="false" but it didnt have an effect. I also tried to intercept the $anchorScroll. also didn't have an effect unfortunately...